Allow unsafe code in this project" does nothing dotnet visual studio code
would you mind helping me to fix this issue I am using dotnet core 7 and trying to make a simple console application that requires unsafe blocks but even I tried to add the attribute of unsafe block in the .csproj file, it didn't work.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project> 

tried to add tasks.json file in .vscode file
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/rest.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary",
                "/unsafe"
            ],

            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }]
} 
b

ut the same issue resists
